# Infimum and Supremum proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I tried to prove: $\inf(A-B) = \inf(A) - \sup(B)$. I was hoping someone could check my proof and perhaps give me some tips, I didn't quite get the ending right. Thanks in advance!

First, I show that $\inf(A-B) = \inf(A) + \inf(-B)$:

Suppose $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. Then $-y \in -B$.

$x \geq \inf(A)$ and $-y \geq \inf(-B)$. This gives us $x-y \geq \inf(A) + \inf(-B)$. So $\inf(A) + \inf(-B)$ is a lower-bound and $\inf(A-B) \geq \inf(A) + \inf(-B)$

Now, suppose $\epsilon>0$. Then $\exists_{x\in A, -y\in -B}$ such that $x < \inf(A) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $-y < \inf(B) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

So $x-y < \inf(A) + \inf(-B) - \epsilon$. This indicates that $\inf(A) + \inf(-B) \geq \inf(A-B)$.

So $\inf(A) + \inf(-B) = \inf(A-B)$.

So now I have to prove that $\inf(-B) = -\sup(B)$. My attempt:

Suppose $y\in B$. Then $y \leq \sup(B)$ this gives $-y \geq -\sup(B)$.

Also $-y \geq \inf(-B)$ by definition. So $\inf(-B) = -\sup(B)$?

Comment: Typo, it should be $-y\in -B$, sorry!

Comment: I didn't read your proof, sorry about that. However, I do have something to say. In those "inf-sup" proofs, always start assuming that all sets have a maximum and a minimum. Prove or disprove your statement in this easy case. Then, just fiddle around with epsilons to have your proof work in the general case.

Comment: But a supremum and infimum doesn't necessarily mean that it has a minimum and a maximum? And how does that help if I assume it does?

Comment: Of course not. $(0,1)$ has no maximum and no minimum.

Comment: But how does the assumption that all sets have a minimum and maximum work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the first portion is correct. Concerning the inf(−B) = −sup(B) portion, consider -sup(B). If you can show that -sup(B) is a lower bound of -B, perhaps by first considering sup(B), the solution should follow by combining a similar result on the -inf(-B) being an upper bound of B, i.e., eventually showing -sup(B) $\leqslant$ inf(-B) and -sup(B) $\geqslant$ inf(-B). Note my work assumes B is a nonempty bounded subset of R.

Comment: Welcome to math.se! You may find [this guide to mathjax formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the first part looks correct to me, but the second part proof seems partial.

Just for comparison, here is essentially the same proof in a 'calculational' style, and avoiding $\epsilon$'s.$\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}\newcommand{\inf}[1]{\text{inf}(#1)}\newcommand{\sup}[1]{\text{sup}(#1)}\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}$

(Notation remarks: I assume we are working in $\;\mathbb R\;$.  Just like in your question, I use 'lifted' notation, so that e.g., $\;A + B\;$ is the set of all $\;a+b\;$ where $\;a \in A\;$ and $\;b \in B\;$.)

Your approach of splitting the proof in two parts is a good one, since it separates two different concerns: we should prove that for any $\;A,B\;$ with a lower bound,
\begin{align}
\tag{1} & \inf{A + B} = \inf{A} + \inf{B} \\
\tag{2} & \inf{A} = {- \sup{-A}} \\
\end{align}
In this answer I will focus on $\ref{1}$.

But first, let's make clear what properties of $\;\inf{\cdots}\;$ we will use.  It seems simplest to just use the definition: given a set $\;A\;$ which has a lower bound, $\;\inf{A}\;$ is the unique real number for which
\begin{align}
\tag{3a} & \langle \forall x : x \in A : \inf{A} \leq x \rangle \\
\tag{3b} & \langle \forall z :: \langle \forall x : x \in A : z \leq x \rangle \;\then\; z \leq \inf{A} \rangle \\
\end{align}
(The first of these says that $\;\inf{A}\;$ is *a* lower bound of $\;A\;$, and the second is that it is *the greatest* lower bound.) And because of the uniqueness, to prove something of the form $\;\inf{A} = E\;$ it suffices to prove both $\;\langle \forall x : x \in A : E \leq x \rangle\;$ and $\;\langle \forall z :: \langle \forall x : x \in A : z \leq x \rangle \;\then\; z \leq E \rangle\;$.

---

Now, let's prove $\ref{1}$.  As I said, because of uniqueness it suffices to prove both $\ref{1a}$ and $\ref{1b}$:
\begin{align}
\tag{1a} & \langle \forall x : x \in A + B : \inf{A} + \inf{B} \leq x \rangle \\
\tag{1b} & \langle \forall z :: \langle \forall x : x \in A + B : z \leq x \rangle \;\then\; z \leq \inf{A} + \inf{B} \rangle \\
\end{align}
Expanding the definition of $\;A + B\;$, we can rewrite these as
\begin{align}
\tag{4a} & \langle \forall a,b : a \in A \land b \in B : \inf{A} + \inf{B} \leq a+b \rangle \\
\tag{4b} & \langle \forall z :: \langle \forall a,b : a \in A \land b \in B : z \leq a+b \rangle \;\then\; z \leq \inf{A} + \inf{B} \rangle \\
\end{align}

Now $\ref{4a}$ directly follows from two applications of $\ref{3a}$: for any $\;a,b\;$,
$$\calc
    \inf{A} + \inf{B} \leq a+b
\op\when\hint{arithmetic}
    \inf{A} \leq a \;\land\; \inf{B} \leq b
\op\when\hint{using $\ref{3a}$ twice, with $\;x := a\;$ and $\;x := b\;$}
    a \in A \;\land\; b \in B
\endcalc$$

Proving $\ref{4b}$ takes slightly longer, but is still pretty direct from two applications of $\ref{3b}$: for any $\;z\;$,
$$\calc
    z \leq \inf{A}+\inf{B}
\op=\hint{arithmetic -- rewrite to prepare for $\ref{3b}$}
    z-\inf{B} \leq \inf{A}
\op\when\hint{by $\ref{0b}$}
    \langle \forall a : a \in A : z-\inf{B} \leq a \rangle
\op=\hint{arithmetic -- rewrite to prepare for $\ref{3b}$}
    \langle \forall a : a \in A : z-a \leq \inf{B} \rangle
\op\when\hint{by $\ref{0b}$}
    \langle \forall a : a \in A : \langle \forall b : b \in B : z-a \leq b \rangle \rangle
\op=\hint{arithmetic; logic: merge quantifications}
    \langle \forall a,b : a \in A \land b \in B : z \leq a+b \rangle
\endcalc$$

This completes the proof of $\ref{1}$.

---

Now before proving $\ref 2$, let's again make explicit the basic properties that we will use, which are very similar to $\ref{3a}$ and $\ref{3b}$: for any $\;C\;$ with an upper bound, $\;\sup{C}\;$ is uniquely determined by
\begin{align}
\tag{5a} & \langle \forall x : x \in C : x \leq \sup{C} \rangle \\
\tag{5b} & \langle \forall z :: \langle \forall x : x \in C : x \leq z \rangle \;\then\; \sup{C} \leq z \rangle \\
\end{align}

---

Again because of uniqueness, for $\ref 2$ it suffices to prove both $\ref{2a}$ and $\ref{2b}$:
\begin{align}
\tag{2a} & \langle \forall x : x \in A : {- \sup{-A}} \leq x \rangle \\
\tag{2b} & \langle \forall z :: \langle \forall x : x \in A : z \leq x \rangle \;\then\; z \leq {- \sup{-A}} \rangle \\
\end{align}

Let's see how we can use the properties of $\;\sup{\cdots}\;$ to prove these: for any $\;x\;$,
$$\calc
    {- \sup{-A}} \leq x
\op=\hint{arithmetic -- to prepare for $\ref{5a}$}
    {-x} \leq \sup{-A}
\op\when\hint{using $\ref{5a}$}
    {-x} \in {-A}
\op=\hint{definition of $\;{-A}\;$}
    x \in A
\endcalc$$
and also for any $\;z\;$,
$$\calc
    z \leq {- \sup{-A}}
\op=\hint{arithmetic -- to prepare for $\ref{5b}$}
    \sup{-A} \leq {-z}
\op\when\hint{using $\ref{5b}$}
    \langle \forall x : x \in {-A} : x \leq {-z} \rangle
\op=\hint{substitute $\;x:={-x}\;$, using the definition of $\;{-A}\;$; simplify using arithmetic}
    \langle \forall x : x \in A : z \leq x \rangle
\endcalc$$
These prove $\ref{2a}$ and $\ref{2b}$, respectively, completing the proof of $\ref{2}$.

Comment: How come you didn't need to use epsilon? And when is it necessary to use epsilon-proof?

Comment: Because I chose to use properties (3a) and (3b) of inf(), which don't talk about epsilon.  It would be helpful (also for yourself) if you made explicit (preferably in your question) which basic properties of inf() and sup() you are using in your proofs.  One of these should mention an epsilon, somewhere.

Comment: Specifically, I think that you are using - what I call - $\text{(3a)}$ together with $$
\tag{3c}
\langle \forall \epsilon : \epsilon > 0 : \langle \exists x : x \in A : x < \text{inf}(A) + \epsilon \rangle \rangle
$$ which is equivalent to my $\text{(3b)}$.